Avoid double quotes removal in bash script (keep double quotes)
I have a run.sh script that is executing a java maven application, so it is passing some parameters the app needs, one of the parameters is a json string (dynamicOptionsJson is the param), but when I try to use this on the app I noticed some errors, checking the value of the String that I pass it prints as {bigqueryTable: table, dummyOption: hehexd} notice it is missing the double quotes of a properly formated json String, but I believe it is getting removed by the bash, please check the .env and run.sh I have:
run.sh:
#!/bin/bash

source ./.env

mvn clean compile exec:java -P dataflow-runner -Dexec.args=" --project=${project} \
--runner=DataflowRunner \
--region=${region} \
--gcpTempLocation=${gcpTempLocation} \
--tempLocation=${tempLocation} \
--serviceAccount=${serviceAccount} \
--dynamicOptionsJson=\"${dynamicOptionsJson}\" \
"

in my .env I have the following:
project=project-name
region=the-region
serviceAccount=an-account
gcpTempLocation=gs://cloud_storage_bucket/temp
tempLocation=gs://cloud_storage_bucket/temp
dynamicOptionsJson='{"bigqueryTable": "table", "dummyOption": "hehexd"}'
#dynamicOptionsJson="{\"bigqueryTable\": \"table\", \"dummyOption\": \"hehexd\"}"

tried to pass the dynamicOptionsJson those ways and no success, it always removes the double quotes so I end up with: {bigqueryTable: table, dummyOption: hehexd}
any idea how can I manage to properly preserve the double quotes? Thanks

This would be easier with a [mcve] without maven and sourcing. When I just set the env variable in a file and source that and echo "$dynamicOptionsJson" I do get the double quotes.

@Robert I will try to upload an example, but I though the problem is there because this maven java app is a dataflow template, a python cloud function calls it and passes the same json string and when I log it, it has the double quotes and everything works ok, but when I pass the string from the script (i mean running the run.sh) it removes the quotes, the argument is received on a PipelineOptions interface that maps it to a java String, edit: I just tried echo the command and you are right it has double quotes, so this is very weird

@Robert but also I think echo works different than executing the command? If I put echo behind the "mvn clean command....." I can see that it has the double quotes still, but maybe when the command is executed it just gets "parsed" and so the quotes are removed?

@Robert I just found the right way to make it work by luck, had to wrap it around single quotes instead of double quotes at the run.sh, going to post an answer to make it clearer

I don't see anything in your code which would mysteriously remove codes, but I would not exclude a problem with the way you construct -Dexec.args. I don't know maven, but if the argument passed here would undergo word splitting somewhere, you would break up your json strings on the whiute spaces.

The way that finally worked to keep the double quotes is to wrap the parameter also with single quotes at the run.sh, heres how:
run.sh:
#!/bin/bash

source ./.env

mvn clean compile exec:java -P dataflow-runner -Dexec.args=" --project=${project} \
--runner=DataflowRunner \
--region=${region} \
--gcpTempLocation=${gcpTempLocation} \
--tempLocation=${tempLocation} \
--serviceAccount=${serviceAccount} \
--dynamicOptionsJson='${dynamicOptionsJson}' \
"

.env:
project=project-name
# other options
dynamicOptionsJson='{"bigqueryTable": "table", "dummyOption": "hehexd"}'
# declaring dynamicOptionsJson like this also works, the trick is using single quotes at run.sh:
dynamicOptionsJson="{\"bigqueryTable\": \"table\", \"dummyOption\": \"hehexd\"}"


dynamicOptionsJson='{"bigqueryTable": "table", "dummyOption": "hehexd"}' and dynamicOptionsJson="{\"bigqueryTable\": \"table\", \"dummyOption\": \"hehexd\"}" store exactly the same value in the dynamicOptionsJson variable. Which is to say -- using single quotes is indeed correct and appropriate, but the syntax the question shows for that particular assignment is equally correct to the one in this answer.

You can test this yourself: Run if [[ '{"bigqueryTable": "table", "dummyOption": "hehexd"}' = "{\"bigqueryTable\": \"table\", \"dummyOption\": \"hehexd\"}" ]]; then echo "identical"; else echo "different"; fi -- you'll see the output is identical.

@CharlesDuffy, yes but that was not my problem mate, even when I pass the second option, if I did not use single quotes at run.sh then it would remove all the double quotes from it, the trick was using single quotes at run.sh too, but yes this both ways of declaring the var at .env are the same you are right in that

That's my point -- that distinction wasn't your problem but you wrote this answer in a way that makes it look like it was.

BTW, if the shell used on the execution side is known to be bash (and the local copy of bash is 5.0 or later), a safer approach ("safer" in the sense that malicious dynamicOptionsJson values can't escape the quoting and run arbitrary commands) would be to use @Q to have the shell escape values for you. --region=${region@Q} --dynamicOptionsJson=${dynamicOptionsJson@Q} etc. Unfortunately that doesn't work if you need to generate commands compatible with /bin/sh -- for that one generally needs to jump into Python and use its shlex module.

To give you an example of why the code in this answer isn't safe as-is, consider if dynamicOptionsJson contains "extraMaliciousOption": "'$(rm -rf ~)'" -- the 's inside the literal data will reverse the 's added by your code, entering an unquoted context where the $(rm -rf ~) will be executed.

@CharlesDuffy thank you mate, your feedback is well received, updated the answer, please feel free to add this info to it too as more notes, I belive it can be very helpful

The existing answer is quite adequate if your configured data is secured and audited just as much as your code is. (Since you're using source, that's a pretty fair assumption: Malicious code mixed into the data can be executed locally during the source operation itself, so the .env file is already inside the trust perimeter). Consider this answer a supplement for folks with different use cases where data is less trusted than the code that's operating on it.

To use a config file format that isn't amenable to the security problems inherent to source, we can replace .env with env.json, as follows:
{
  "region": "the-region",
  "serviceAccount": "an-account",
  "gcpTempLocation": "gs://cloud_storage_bucket/temp",
  "tempLocation": "gs://cloud_storage_bucket/temp",
  "dynamicOptionsJson": "{\"bigqueryTable\": \"table\", \"dummyOption\": \"hehexd\"}"
}

...then we can use:
#!/bin/bash

# use jq to generate shell assignments from a JSON file, with @sh escaping
# variable names must start with a lower-case character; this protects security-
# sensitive all-caps variable names like PATH or LD_PRELOAD
varsFromJson() {
  jq -r '
    to_entries[]
    | select(.key | test("^[[:lower:]][[:alnum:]]+$"))
    | "\(.key)=\(.value | @sh)"
  '
}

# a less security-sensitive alternative to ''source .env''
eval "$(varsFromJson <env.json)" || exit

quote() { python3 -c 'import shlex, sys'$'\n''print(" ".join(shlex.quote(x) for x in sys.argv[1:]))' "$@"; }

# define an array of arguments
cmd=(
  --project="$project"
  --runner=DataflowRunner
  --region="$region"
  --gcpTempLocation="$gcpTempLocation"
  --tempLocation="$tempLocation"
  --serviceAccount="$serviceAccount"
  --dynamicOptionsJson="$dynamicOptionsJson"
)

cmdStr=$(quote "${cmd[@]}") # convert that array to a string

# pass the string to mvn
mvn clean compile exec:java -P dataflow-runner -Dexec.args="$cmdStr"

This way we make preexisting, audited software (jq and Python) responsible for determining how to safely quote and escape the data. (In practice, the Python shlex module will add single quotes, just as the OP did by hand in their existing answer -- but with the benefit that if the data also contains literal single quotes, shlex will do the necessary work to escape them; also, by replacing source with jq, we prevent source .env from running arbitrary code, and can limit which shell variables it's able to set or override to protect variables in the reserved all-caps namespace that can modify shell or OS-component behavior).
